# Error Mounting ADLS on DBFS for Databricks (Error: NullPointerException)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, databricks, azure-data-lake

I am trying to mount Azure Data Lake Gen 2 in Databricks getting the error seen below.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: authEndpoint

The code I am using is shown below

```
configs = {
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.auth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.auth2.client.id": "<client-id>",
  "fs.azure.account.auth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "scope1", key = "kvsecretfordbricks"),
  "dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "abfss://starter1@newresourcegroupadcadls.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/demo",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

The full error is given below

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ExecutionError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 9     source = "abfss://starter1@newresourcegroupadcadls.dfs.core.windows.net/",
> 10     mount_point = "/mnt/demo",
> ---> 11   extra_configs = configs)
>
> /local_disk0/tmp/1612619970782-0/dbutils.py in
> f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
> 312                     exc.**context** = None
> 313                     exc.**cause** = None
> --> 314                     raise exc
> 315             return f_with_exception_handling
> 316
>
> ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o271.mount. :
> java.lang.NullPointerException: authEndpoint  at
> shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
> at
> shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenUsingClientCreds(AzureADAuthenticator.java:84)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureOAuth(DBUtilsCore.scala:477)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureFileSystem(DBUtilsCore.scala:488)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.mount(DBUtilsCore.scala:446)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor292.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any help would be appreciated

When I run

```
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt")
```

There are no mount points beginning with "/mnt"

--

UPDATE

Additional Error Message after updating `dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url` as `fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint`

> ExecutionError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 9     source = "abfss://starter1@newresourcegroupadcadls.dfs.core.windows.net/",
> 10     mount_point = "/mnt/demo",
> ---> 11   extra_configs = configs)
>
> /local_disk0/tmp/1612858508533-0/dbutils.py in
> f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
> 312                     exc.**context** = None
> 313                     exc.**cause** = None
> --> 314                     raise exc
> 315             return f_with_exception_handling
> 316
>
> ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o275.mount. :
> java.lang.NullPointerException: clientId  at
> shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
> at
> shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenUsingClientCreds(AzureADAuthenticator.java:85)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureOAuth(DBUtilsCore.scala:477)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureFileSystem(DBUtilsCore.scala:488)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.mount(DBUtilsCore.scala:446)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account to DBFS, please update  `dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url` as `fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint`. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2#--mount-an-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-using-a-service-principal-and-oauth-20) and [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0_Client_Credentials)

For example

1. Create an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account.

```
az login
az storage account create \
    --name <account-name> \
    --resource-group <group name> \
    --location westus \
    --sku Standard_RAGRS \
    --kind StorageV2 \
    --enable-hierarchical-namespace true
```

2. Create a service principal and assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to the sp in the scope of the Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account

```
az login

az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --scopes /subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

3. Create a Spark cluster in Azure Databricks
4. mount Azure data lake gen2 in Azure databricks(python)

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/demo",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

[image]

4. Check

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/demo")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 

Updated `dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url` as `fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint`

Now getting the error message "java.lang.NullPointerException"

The Client ID is definitely correct, any ideas?

Comment: @user15037183 Could you please provide the whole error message?

Comment: ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o275.mount.
: java.lang.NullPointerException: clientId
 at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)

Comment: As the full error message is very long - I have included above in the original post (see the bottom, Update section)

Comment: @user15037183 According to the error, it seems that the client id is not right? COuld you please check it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

I have checked it & it's definitely right

Comment: Could it be because the Pricing Tier for my dbricks workspace is "Free Trial" and not "Premium" ?

Comment: @user15037183 The issue does not relate to the price tier. I have tested it. The free tire is ok for me。 Have you referred to https://kb.databricks.com/data-sources/access-blob-fails-wasb.html?_ga=2.179512359.2087349870.1613133425-334605003.1613133425

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue using free tier, after much research and deliberation, found out that there is no issue with free tier. I just recreated the **clientsecret**, **clientid** and **tenantid** in the Azure keyvault. And after that I recreated the scope in Databricks and now everything seems to be working fine.

Anyone who faces such an issue can refer to this tutorial to correctly implement "Connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using service principal" by Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/getting-started/connect-to-azure-storage

or

https://deep.data.blog/2019/03/28/avoiding-error-403-request-not-authorized-when-accessing-adls-gen-2-from-azure-databricks-while-using-a-service-principal/